# Rails4: How do I change the way particular URL helpers works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

### The goal

No log in screens!
A visitor to the site should be able to create a widget without logging in.

This widget is publically accessible and can be shared via a short URL.
To edit this widget, you need to know the longer, administration URL.

The show action should have a URL with a short token instead of an id:

```
widget_path(widget)        # => /widget/abc123
```

The edit action should have a URL with a long token instead of an id:

```
widget_path(widget)        # => /widget/abcdefghijklmnop123/edit
```

### What I have so far:

**Generating tokens**

I'm using a `before_create` callback to generate two tokens, a `token` and an `admin_token` with `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`.

Then, to change the URL helpers from generating URLs with the id, I override the `to_param` method in the model to return the `token`:

```
def to_param
  token
end
```

Now when I save a new record, a token gets generated and the url helpers return these:

```
widget_path(widget)        # => /widget/abc123
edit_widget_path(widget)   # => /widget/abc123/edit
```

### The problem

I need the `edit_widget_path` helper to use the `admin_token` field.

I can't seem to find a way of doing this.
In an ideal solution, I would want the `_url` versions of these to also work and they should be available in the usual places (controllers and views).
The closest I have found is to create custom `_path` and `_url` methods in `ApplicationController`, but this doesn't seem right.

Open to suggestions for how to achieve this.
Is there a way to use Rails' existing mechanism for generating URL helpers?

I hope that makes sense, feel free to ask for clarification.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering where the logic of this non-standard URL should live. The model seems very wrong, the (application)controller sort of fits, but it seems like it needs to be in the route file, but unfortunately the url helpers can not interpret '/widgets/:token' to mean they need to call the :token method on a widget to generate that sort of url...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any rails mechanism that could handle that except inheritance. You could implement a subclass and override the `to_param` method there. I don't think that this is worth doing so, since you just want to handle 1 route here. I think I would just create a helper method to handle that case.

Another hint here: You could use the same mechanism that GIT uses. Create a UUID (long version) and use the first X digits to make the public url, just the full UUID is secret. This works in GIT 99,9% of the time without collisions, so it should work for you as well.